# How can I figure out which cloud server is the closest / has the lowest latency for a given geolocation?

Tags: cloud

I want to write a script, which automatically connects me to the cloud service provider which is "closest" to me. More specific, I want to figure out which cloud provider will give me the lowest latency *if* I'd set up a VM there. Then, I set up a VM of this provider and connect myself to it.

I am unsure if this is even possible because I couldn't find any lists of servers from cloud providers or similar online. As an example, for Azure I only found server regions, I could choose from when I create a VM there.

My original plan was to ping all available cloud servers from all large providers (azure,
aws, ...) which are closer than `x` km to a given geolocation and set up a VM on the server with the lowest latency. As this seems to be impossible, does anybody have an idea, what could be an alternative way of solving my issue?